# Composite Design Pattern in Scala

Tags: design-patterns, scala

The following is a personal attempt at implementing the [Composite design pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) in Scala. `Observation` is abstract...

```
class CompositeObservation(obss: Observation*) extends Observation {
  val elements: MutableList[Observation] = new MutableList[Observation]()

  elements ++ obss

  def hasElement(o: Observation): Boolean = elements.contains(o);
}
```

`hasElement` fails to return if an element is contained in the composite. Questions:

1. Am I misinterpreting the ++ operator? The Observation*?
2. What is the most ideomatic way to implement this pattern in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `++` returns a *new* collection, you need `++=` here
2. Your attempt looks fine to me. Maybe you should additionally implement the `Traversable` trait or so, and delegate the calls to `elements` in order to make things a little bit more convenient.

**[Edit]**

```
class CompositeObservation(obss: Observation*) 
     extends Observation with Traversable[Observation] {

  val elements = new MutableList[Observation]()

  elements ++= obss

  def hasElement(o: Observation): Boolean = elements.contains(o);

  def foreach[U](f: (Observation) => U): Unit = elements.foreach(f)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the ++=. I like the idea of Traversable (akin to IEnumerable in C#). Could you provide me an example of how to do that "elengatly"?

Comment: @Hugo S Ferreira: It's really easy. I added the code.

Comment: thx. I realize the `: Unit = ...` can be replaced by `{ ... }` Any particular reason I'm not aware for you to have used it?

Comment: I copied the definiton of foreach from somewhere :-) But for beginners I would recommend to write out always the return type for methods, as it is easy to forget the `=` between arg list and method body (especially as ist looks like Java), and you search for hours why your method doesn't work.